# How to fix ASP.NET Core File Upload empty file

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to upload a csv file from Angular to Asp.NET Core webapi.
But getting empty object at the web abi although Fiddler shows something went over the network.
I am using Kendo UI to upload the file.

Can you please tell me how to resolve this ? I tried [FromBody] and [FromForm] but no difference.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(ApiRoutes.EodVariationMargin)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPlugAsync(object plugs)
    {
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(plugs); 
        _logger.LogInformation(content);
        return Ok();
    }

Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      1,470      (headers:539; body:931)
Bytes Received:  198        (headers:198; body:0)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    11:34:36.511
ClientBeginRequest: 11:34:44.561
GotRequestHeaders:  11:34:44.561
ClientDoneRequest:  11:34:44.566
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    11:34:36.512
FiddlerBeginRequest:    11:34:44.566
ServerGotRequest:   11:34:44.566
ServerBeginResponse:    11:35:15.629
GotResponseHeaders: 11:35:15.629
ServerDoneResponse: 11:35:15.629
ClientBeginResponse:    11:35:15.629
ClientDoneResponse: 11:35:15.630

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:31.069

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
~headers~: 198
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this and it works:

```
[Route("API/files")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("Upload")]
    public IActionResult SaveUploaded()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        var files = this.Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("Destination"))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }
            result.Add(file.FileName);
        }
        return result.ToJson();
    }
}
```

And Angular html:

```
<kendo-upload saveUrl="API/Files/Upload"
              ...>
</kendo-upload>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. `this.Request.Form.Files` is the solution. My method signature `public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPlugAsync(IFormFile filePayload)` as I also use the Swagger interface to test the method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to an action param of type `object`. Rather, I suppose you *can* but it won't do anything for you because `object` has no properties. Hence, the modelbinder will simply discard everything that's posted.

If you're trying to accept an upload in that param, then it should be of type `IFormFile`. If you're trying to accept a JSON payload, then it should be an actual *class* that you create to represent that payload. For example, if you were sending JSON like:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Then, you need a class like:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

If you're trying to send an upload as part of your JSON payload, then your DTO class should have a `byte[]` property named after the key of the file upload, and your upload data should be sent as Base 64. For example:

```
{
    // other stuff
    "file": "{base64 encoded byte array}"
}
```

With a DTO like:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    // other properties
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed parameter to `IFormFile` so I could use Swagger to test the method.